# Is there any reason for initializing iterations of a loop from zero instead of one when not using arrays?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, initialization

I mean

```
for (int i=1; i<7; i++)
```

is much more readable when it is purely for the number of iterations that

```
for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
```

but somewhat the other approach has become an standard.

What do you think? It´s a bad practice or discouraged?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's simply because arrays are almost always 0-based, that when designers create other non-array objects that have collections, they have a tendency to make them 0-based as well. 0-based is just a standard, so sticking to it is just consistency and ease of use for maintainers.

Also, to me,

`for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {`

is more readable because I know that when 1 loop has completed, the count (`i`) will be one. With 1-based, after the first loop, the count is `i = 2`. This throws me off a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Convention. Zero indexing is so widespread and historically prevalent that, unless there is a specific reason to do otherwise, it is what programmers expect to see. If they see a loop indexed from 1, they usually don't think "Ah, that's easier to read," they think "Oh, better figure out why we're starting from one here."

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that

```
for (int i=1; i<7; i++)
```

is harder to read than

```
for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
```

because it is `6` iterations. You need to subtract `1` from `7` to figure that out seeing the first loop.

The two options are usually start at `0` and use `<` as your condition, or start at `1` and use `<=` as your condition like so:

```
for (int i=1; i<=6; i++)
```

Note that some languages (e.g. MATLAB) do index everything starting at 1.

What usually happens is that all the loops in the language follow the indexing convention of its most basic/widely-used naturally indexed construct. In Java, arrays are indexed at `0`, and because it's a pain to switch from 0-based indexing to 1-based indexing and back, everything becomes 0-indexed.

For comparison, in MATLAB the arrays and matrices are 1-indexed, so all the loops are typically 1-indexed as well.

Answer (score 0):

It stems back to the c pointer days  (my c is rusty so forgive me).'
THe following is an array declaration in c

```
int arr[10] = { ... };
```

In reality, the "arr" variable is actually of type "int *" (but declaring it as above lets the compiler force automatic cleanup when it falls out of scope, as opposed to an int * with a malloc), which points to a memory location which has enough contiguous space for 10 int values.  Then you access the array:

```
int element = arr[index];
```

What's really going on in the access is this:

```
int element = * (arr + index*sizeof(int));
```

It's taking the pointer, adding enough bytes to pointer to point at the memory location for element you're interested in (the part in the parens), and then dereferencing it to get the value (the *).

So, for the very first element in the array, your index is 0, because the pointer is already pointing at the first element, so you don't add anything to the memory location.

Think of the index as "how many slots do i have to add to my pointer to find what i want".